# How do we style and create a custom request for notification permission?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I happen to be using firebase in a react PWA app and triggering the permission screen with a fetch function calling

```
Notification.requestPermission().then((result) => {
    if (result === 'granted') {
     getToken(messaging, {
     vapidKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_VAPID_KEY,
    })
.
.
.
```

But I am curious how sites are able to customize the notification permission dialog.  I imagine it might not work the same for all browsers, but I am struggling to find anything about it for chrome and mobile browsers.  Since I am using firebase messaging, I wonder if there is a better way to request permission than the getToken() function?